# How to fix the UiPath Invalid Machine Key Robot Error?

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-orchestrator, uipath-robot, uipath-activity

When I try to connect to UiPath Orchestra from the Assistant I get an Invalid Machine Key error.

I do have the correct machine key as you can see from the matching values in Orchestrator and the Assistant.

[image]

Any idea how to fix the UiPath Invalid Machine Key error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply missing one letter at the end.

[image]

Always make sure to use the Copy Text Icon on the right side, instead of marking the text on your own. That prevents such kind of issue. Hope that helped.

Comment: Omg. That was it. So dumb.

Answer (score 0):

It indeed looks like a digit was accidentally trimmed off the end there during the copy and paste process. Always ensure you don't trim off any digits or add any additional whitespace or non-standard characters when you paste in the key.

[image]

### Alternate explanation

Just for the sake of others who may come to this StackOverflow question with the same problem, it's worth nothing that this [UiPath machine key error](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Fix-UiPath-Invalid-Machine-Key-Robot-Error) can also be thrown when there's a mismatch between the `hostname` of the local machine and the machine name used when creating the machine resource on UiPath Orchstrator.

[image]

Another issue is simply the fact that there can be so many machines configured on UiPath Orchestrator, the [machine error](https://youtu.be/YyuB_qOC8ec) may be caused by something as simply as copying from the wrong resource.

Make sure the hostnames are correct, make sure you copied the key for the correct machine and ensure the code is pasted without trimming or adding any characters accidentally. Get that right and you'll have your [UiPath robots](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Create-your-first-RPA-robot-to-UiPath-Orchestrator-tutorial) up and running in no time.